# Re-Drawing Html5 Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I've a chart and a grid, the former can be hidden/shown by clicking on some checkbox. Could anyone come up with a meta code, demonstrating the most performant approach for doing that? I can't see anything better other than re-drawing the whole canvas each time my 'Show Grid' setting gets changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two canvas nodes; one for the chart and the other for the grid on top of it.

Then you can just hide (`style.display = "none"`) the grid element or show it (`style.display = "block"`).

A canvas pixel includes alpha, so it can be completely transparent (this is actually the default when a canvas is created) therefore you can see chart through the grid.

Comment: Thanks, what about more complex scenario - if I've a few 'dynamic' areas - would it not be an overkill to have a dedicated canvas for each 'dynamic' future? How many canvas can be stacked up w/out compromising performance?

Comment: Browsers are pretty good at managing even hundreds of canvas elements. Note that there is really not much of a difference for the browser graphic engine between a canvas and an `<img>` node and you normally see many images in a webpage. Also since hiding/showing is not going to be an animation but only a reaction to a user interaction the speed should not be a problem even on less powerful devices like phones or tablets.